# Move a video within a div

Tags: css, html, video

I'm creating a website with a videoheader.
Everything goes fine with the implementation.
Though one thing isn't going good.

Actually I should be able to reposition the video within a div in orde to see another piece of the content. (see screenshot)
[image: Screenshot]

What I want is that the video will go up, so that I can see the lower part of the video.

Now there is an overflow after 505px of height.

Can someone help me with this?

The css I used:

```
#cover
{
    width: auto;
    height: 505px;
}

.header-unit1
{
    height: 505px;
    border-right:none;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

#video-container1
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-10;
}

#video-container1
{
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:505px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#testvid video
{
    position:absolute;
}

#testvid video.fillWidth1
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any tips would be nice!

Comment: What's the link to the page? (never normally ask that) but I don't know how it will react to certain things.

Comment: Provide a link, a fiddle, or at least all the code involved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea of what (*I think*) you're trying to accomplish:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <video ...></video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   width:100%;
   height: 505px;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}

video{
   max-width:100%;
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
}
```

Then animate the video top position. You can do this with Javascript or add another class like `video.animated { top: 50px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reactions.

I applied `margin-top: -250px;` to the video element which gave me another frame of the video, exactly what I needed.
For example, I now see the people walking in stead of the blue sky.